How to install PyQt 6 Designer in Ubuntu 24.10
How to install PyQt6 on 24.10?
Something broke when I upgraded from 24.04 to 24.10. The PyQt6 designer program was still in /usr/bin, but some dependency must have broken and it wouldn't run.

Any reason for upgrading from 24.04 to 24.10? I think 24.04 is more stable.

@Basilthedev - I simply like to be on the latest release.

@guiverc so many rules.  I was excited to be able to provide an answer to a current situation.  All the other answers I looked at were for older ubuntus and older designers.

After many searches and many failures I found this:
sudo apt install qt6-base-dev
sudo apt install qt6-tools-dev

This got me a working designer.  Then if you create ~/.local/share/application/desginer.desktop with this contents:
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Qt Designer 6
Comment=Qt Designer 6
Exec=/usr/lib/qt6/bin/designer
Icon=/home/larry/.local/share/applications/qt_designer.ico
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;

then:
chmod 755 designer.desktop

Now it will appear with your other applicatiions
